# Does spell resistance from Oath of Ancients protect against dragon breath attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin, dragons, damage-resistance

I'm trying to find some clarification on something that seems a little vague to me: I'm going to be turning level 7 soon as a Paladin, and my oath gives me resistance against spell damage.

I'm not sure if breath attacks count as spells, since there is nothing to clarify either way IMO. The save DC for a dragonborn PC is calculated exactly the same way as a spell would, they deal the same types of damage as spells, and the DMG says dragons are innately magical, so does dragon breath count as spell damage for the purpose of Oath of Ancients spell damage resistance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A breath weapon is not a spell.

From the [Dragonborn](http://www.5esrd.com/races/dragonborn) entry:

> Breath Weapon: You can use your action to exhale destructive energy. Your draconic ancestry determines the size, shape, and damage type of the exhalation.

Spells require some combination of Verbal, Somatic, and Material components.
A breath weapon requires... exhalation...

The introduction to [spellcasting](http://www.5esrd.com/spellcasting) says:

> Spell Level
>
> **Every spell has a level** from 0 to 9.

A breath weapon doesn't have a level. Therefore, it is not a spell.

Comment: Fair enough, the fact it doesnt have a level makes sense.

Comment: Very nice duck-typing. If it doesn't quack like a duck, it ain't a duck!